# How to sum values of a matrix according to colnames and rownames?

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have the following matrix:

```
     Aa   AA
aa    1    0
Aa    31   1
AA    7    3590
```

how to say in R that I want to sum values within the matrix which do not correspond in terms of column names and row names, in this case:
1 (Aa versus aa), 7 (Aa versus AA), 0 (AA versus aa), 1 (AA versus Aa), so as to get 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `outer` to compare the rownames and column names, leaving a logical matrix of the same dimensions as the original. This can be used to subset the original matrix, which is then summed. That means the following one-liner should do the trick:

```r
sum(m[!outer(rownames(m), colnames(m), `==`)])
#> [1] 9
```

---

**Data used:**

```r
m <- structure(c(1, 31, 7, 0, 1, 3590), dim = 3:2, dimnames = list(
  c("aa", "Aa", "AA"), c("Aa", "AA")))

m
#>    Aa   AA
#> aa  1    0
#> Aa 31    1
#> AA  7 3590
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fill two matrices of the same dimensions with the original rownames and colnames and then compare the two:

```r
# create dummy data
m <- matrix(c(1, 31, 7, 0, 1, 3590), ncol = 2)
colnames(m) <- c("Aa", "AA")
rownames(m) <- c("aa", "Aa", "AA")

# compare rownames with colnames as matrices
mr <- rep(rownames(m), times = ncol(m)) |> matrix(ncol = ncol(m))
mc <- rep(colnames(m), times = nrow(m)) |> matrix(nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)

# sum
sum(m[mr != mc])
#> [1] 9
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or convert into a (long) dataframe, filter, and sum:

```r
as.data.frame(as.table(m), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) |> 
  filter(Var1 != Var2) |> 
  pull(Freq) |> 
  sum()
```